# Определить является ли ссылка файлом

Tags: php

Пишу парсер для сайта, и когда он натыкается вот на такие ссылки:
http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.21/x64/node-v0.10.21-x64.msi

Начинает хорошо тормозить. В общем мне не нужно работать с файлами в данной ситуации, возможно как-то определить является ли ссылка файлом ?

или определить размер ссылки. Ссылки внешние, потому не все функции можно применить.

Подскажите пожалуйста решение.

Comment: CURL в помощь. Ну и еще *перед* ним проверять известные расширения что ли.

Comment: вот по поводу расширений тоже была идея, но есть же сайты, которые генерируют ссылку для файла типа site.ru/bjF943c.

Подскажите пожалуйста по курлу куда копать ?

Comment: ...тем более CURL вычислит размер и по `short URL`

Answer (score 1):

В коммент не получится - пишу в ответ. Обрабатывайте хедеры.

```
http://goo.gl/xESDuF
```

[image]

Comment: Тут тоже 1 момент, когда я получаю заголовки файла, он достаточно долго подгружается. 

Тоесть нужно как то обойти его подгрузку. Вариант обработать все расширения и не пускать к загрузке ссылки с раширением такие как .rar и тп. 

А вот с такими как у вас урлами походу никак ?

Comment: А почему *долго подгружается*?

Comment: попадаются файлы по 5 - 100 мб.

Comment: Да, но ведь можно же использовать `get_headers`? Я просто не вижу зависимости скорости от размера того *контента*, что *предлагается* в ответ.